# Need some help writing a custom jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Please take a look at the following:

```
jQuery.fn.jqPos = function(target, settings) {
    settings = jQuery.extend({
        offset: [ 0, 0 ]
    }, settings);

    return this.each(function() {
        magic($(this), target, settings);
        $(window).resize(function(){
            magic($(this), target, settings);
        });
    });

    function magic(self, target, settings) {
        // Here I position self close to target
    }
};
```

This works perfectly when I first initialize the plugin, like `$('div#one').jqPos($('div#two'));` and the magic method runs as it should. But at the event `window.resize` nothing happens at all (I want it to run the same method with the same settings and parameters)!

How come? And how to overcome?

**EDIT:** In the magic-method (at window.resize), the arguments are all `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre confusing what `this` refers to in your `$(window).resize(function(){
            magic($(this), target, settings);
        });`
 `this` no longer refers to your element but rather the `window` itself. try:

```
 return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        magic($this, target, settings);
        $(window).resize(function(){
            magic($this, target, settings);
        });
    });
```